# Outputting/Testing of Code within Google Cloud Shell Editor

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, slack-api

Hopefully you are safe and well.

During this lockdown my company moved to Slack. As a bit of a WFH hobby, about a week ago I started to learn how to code basic Slack apps within Google Cloud. The reason for this message is to ask a novice question, so please forgive me. Is there a way to test/ output/ compile code within Google Cloud without having to go through the steps to send it to Slack and test within that eco-system. I imagine not, as I've looked through the platform and help files.

Many thanks for any help with this question.

Best wishes,

David

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you mean? Cloud Shell is the CLI manage your projects and resources without having to install the Google Cloud SDK or other tools on your system. It is true that it comes with a [built-in code editor](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/viewing-and-editing-files#viewing_and_editing_files), and a [web app previewer](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview), but definetely not a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Shell runs a docker container, with many language SDK's already installed.

> Developers will enjoy access to all their favorite
>   development tools pre-configured. You’ll find Java, Go, Python,
>   Node.js, PHP, and Ruby development and deployment tools. Run your web
>   applications inside the Cloud Shell instance and preview them from the
>   browser. Then commit it back to your repo with the pre-configured git
>   and Mercurial clients.

So yes, you can actually **test/output/compile** all your Java, Go, Python, Node.js, PHP, and Ruby code.

For example it comes out of the box with:

- Maven for **Java**.
- NPM for **NodeJS**.
- PIP for **Python**.

And many others.

If you are using NodeJS to code Slack apps, you can even run **Visual Studio Code** in Google Cloud Shell:

```
export VERSION=`curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/cdr/code-server/releases/latest | grep -oP '"tag_name": "\K(.*)(?=")'`
wget https://github.com/cdr/code-server/releases/download/$VERSION/code-server-$VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf code-server-$VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd code-server-$VERSION-linux-x86_64
./code-server --no-auth --port 8080
```

[image]

For reference the code and image for VS Code were taken from this [medium post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-run-visual-studio-code-in-google-cloud-shell-354d125d5748).

Please check the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/shell) for the most up-to-date list of supported languages.